# Does it make sense to do PCA after robust PCA?

Tags: pca, robust

I was wondering whether it makes sense to do PCA after robust PCA. Suppose I have a matrix $X$ and if I do robust PCA I would get:

$$X=A+E$$

And if I do PCA over $A$ would this make sense as a preprocessing step? The matrix $X$ is highly sparse (less than 10% is populated, with a size of 15K by 20K).

An introduction to [robust PCA](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/RobustPCA.pdf), if more specific details are needed: I would like to use [the inexact ALM method](http://perception.csl.illinois.edu/matrix-rank/sample_code.html) to do this.

My objective is to reduce the dimensionality of $X$, but it contains some extreme outliers.

Comment: Robust PCA of Candes et al. decomposes matrix $X$ into matrix $A$ that has low rank (and is not sparse) and a matrix $E$ that is sparse (and is not low rank). So $A$ is supposed to be low rank. What's the point of another PCA step then? You did not specify what is the goal of your analysis; what is it supposed to be a preprocessing step for? Apart from that, I am not sure that robust PCA makes sense when $X$ is sparse; it is based on the assumption that $A$ is non-sparse and low rank, hence it seems to me that $X$ is supposed to be a dense matrix for robust PCA to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense.

Classical PCA is highly sensitive to outliers.
By using robust PCA, you can identify these outliers and get rid of them.

About Classical PCA:

- PCA is sensitive to outliers
- PCA does not require distributional assumptions
- PCA only considers orthogonal transformations (rotations) of the original variables)
- Dimension reduction can only be achieved if the original variables were correlated. Otherwise, PCA is only re-ordering them according to their variance!!!
- PCA is not scale invariant. Often (but not always) scaling is preferred.